# OSError: Java command failed for corenlp in python to get text POS tagging, segmentation, parsing

Tags: python, java, nlp

I am trying to get POS tags for Arabic language using NLTK and stanford coreNLP using Python. the problem that I am facing is

```
OSError: Java command failed : ['C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java.exe', '-mx1000m', '-cp', 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/الجامعة الالمانية/CoreNLP/stanford-tagger-4.2.0/stanford-postagger-full-2020-11-17/stanford-postagger.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger', '-model', 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/الجامعة الالمانية/CoreNLP/stanford-tagger-4.2.0/stanford-postagger-full-2020-11-17/models/arabic.tagger', '-textFile', 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpk9yh0phm', '-tokenize', 'false', '-outputFormatOptions', 'keepEmptySentences', '-encoding', 'utf-8']
```

I am trying to understand the error where everything in my code is clear and the paths are correct.
here is the code

```
import nltk
from nltk import *
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java.exe'

jar = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/الجامعة الالمانية/CoreNLP/stanford-tagger-4.2.0/stanford-postagger-full-2020-11-17/stanford-postagger.jar"
model = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/الجامعة الالمانية/CoreNLP/stanford-tagger-4.2.0/stanford-postagger-full-2020-11-17/models/arabic.tagger"

pos_tagger = StanfordPOSTagger(model, jar, encoding = "utf-8")

text = open("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/test.txt", encoding="utf8").read()
 
words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tagged_words = pos_tagger.tag(words)
print(tagged_words)
```

can you help me in this please? I have spent a long time to solve it but it still gives me the same error weather for text POS tagging, text segmentation, and text Parsing.
Thank you